# I have to exchange position from {a=8, b=4, c=3} to expecting {a=8, c=3, b=4} in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am getting output {a=8, b=4, c=3} in hashmap:

```java
String value = "aaaaacccbbbbaaa";
HashMap<Character, Integer> hashdata=new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
         
char[] data=value.toCharArray();
for (char c : data) {
    if (hashdata.containsKey(c)) {
        hashdata.put(c, hashdata.get(c)+1);
    } else {
        hashdata.put(c, 1);
    }
}

System.out.println(hashdata);
```

But I am expecting output {a=8, c=3, b=4}. How can I exchange position?

Comment: A `LinkedHashMap` maintains order of insertion. `Map<Character, Integer> hashdata = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
`

Comment: [HashMap: This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) - Wanting a specific order form a HashMap is a futile exercise. If you want a deterministic order you need to use another implementation of Map

Comment: Your loop body can be `hashdata.compute(c, (k, v) -> v == null? 1 : v+1);`

Comment: Are you sure that the ordering is a requirement of your task?

Comment: 1. `HashMap` has no ordering guarantee. 2. `toString()` has no format guarantee. If this is a genuine requirement send it back with these comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`.

- `HashMap` is an unordered & unsorted
- `LinkedHashMap` is an ordered and sorted by insertion time of elements:
  `aaaaacccbbbbaaa` (**a** - first, **c** - second, **b** - third)

Example:

```
Map<Character, Integer> hashdata = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maps are inherently unordered.  As has been suggested, `LinkedHashMap` preserves the insertion order.  There are many ways to accomplish this including yours.  Here are two of the same except one uses `Map<String,Integer>` the other uses `Map<Character,Integer>`

The Map.merge function takes the `key` (what your counting), and a value.  If the key is absent or the value is null, null is replaced by the value for the given key.  Otherwise, the value is remapped using the mapping function `(Integer::sum)` using the supplied value `(1)`.

Given

```
 String value = "aaaaacccbbbbaaa";
```

The first example, uses a `Character` as the map key; iterating over the character array, and wrapping the existing `char` in a `Character` object.

```
Map<Character, Integer> freq4 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(char ch : value.toCharArray()) {
   freq4.merge(Character.valueOf((char)ch), 1, Integer::sum);
}
 
System.out.println(freq);
```

This splits the string on an empty string which essentially splits between each character, resulting in an array of single character strings.

```
Map<String, Integer> freq = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(String chstr : value.split("")) {
      freq3.merge(chstr, 1, Integer::sum);
}
System.out.println(freq);
```

Both print

```
{a=8, c=3, b=4}
```